# Unable to make outbound PPTP Connection through DD-WRT

Tags: router, vpn, dd-wrt, pptp

I am unable to make outbound connections to an external PPTP VPN. All of my testing seems to indicate it is an issue with my DD-WRT Configuration on our router.

Here's what I have and what I know:

We have several laptops (OSX and Windows) that are used to connect to a customer's external (off network, out of our control) PPTP VPN. When these machines are on our internal network, they cannot connect to the remote VPN. When they are not on our internal network (connecting from home, tethered to a phone, etc), they can connect to the customer's VPN just fine and without altering the machine's VPN configuration.

The only thing that I can come up with is the traffic is somehow being blocked by our router. Our internal network is behind an ASUS RT-AC66U running DD-WRT  build 25015.

`DD-WRT v24-sp2 (09/16/14) kongac - build 25015M`

All connections are via Ethernet.

This site (and others) seem to have plenty of information on diagnosing Error 619 for inbound PPTP connections to within a DD-WRT-controlled network, but nothing seems to have any ideas on if the issues are for an outbound PPTP connection. If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it.

### Errors

*On OSX*
A connection could not be established to the PPP server. Try reconnecting. If the problem continues, verify your settings and contact your Administrator.

*On Windows*
Error 619: A connection to the remote computer could not be established, so the port used for this connection was closed.

### Router Configuration

For VPN Passthrough: IPSec, PPTP, and L2TP Passthrough are all enabled.

[image: VPN Passthrough Settings]

We do not have our own inbound VPN connection; machines do not connect to our network via VPN. The Router's PPTP Server is disabled. We do not want the Router to connect to the Customers VPN, only specific machines. The Router's PPTP Client Options are disabled. WAN Connection Type is Automatic / DHCP.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This hopefully is fixed in a recent DD-WRT fix: http://svn.dd-wrt.com/changeset/25126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed with [DD-WRT Changeset 25126](http://svn.dd-wrt.com/changeset/25126).

Any of the recent [Brainslayer builds](ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/) for DD-WRT after 25126 appear to resolve the issue. I have been running build [25309](ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/2014/11-11-2014-r25309/) for about a week without any issues.

So, the answer seems to simply be to upgrade to the latest version.